# analyzing .WAV files

Tags: c++, audio, wav

I'm currently working with .WAV files and i have a question.

my way to approach this was to create a struct that will contain the information:

```
typedef struct header_file{
    char chunk_id[4];
    int chunk_size;
    char format[4];
    char subchunk1_id[4];
    int subchunk1_size;
    short int audio_format;
    short int num_channels;
    int sample_rate;           
    int byte_rate;
    short int block_align;
    short int bits_per_sample;
    char subchunk2_id[4];
    int subchunk2_size; 
}header;

typedef struct header_file* wav_p;
```

now,  i tried to run over  the WAV file like the following:

```
    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open("file.txt");
    FILE * file = fopen("file.wav", "rb");

    const int BUFFSIZE = 256;                           
    int count = 0;                                      
    short int buff[BUFFSIZE];                           
    wav_p wav = (wav_p)malloc(sizeof(header));
    int nb;                                             

    if (file)
    {
        fread(wav, 1, sizeof(header), file);    
        while (!feof(file)){
            nb = fread(buff, 1, BUFFSIZE, file);
            count++;

            for (int i = 0; i<BUFFSIZE; i += 1){
                //the following part i found on the internet so i'm not sure if it is good
                int h = (signed char)buff[i + 1];
                int c = (h << 8) | buff[i];
                double t = c / 32768.0;

                myFile << t << endl;
                if(abs(t)>1){
                //checking that a value is between -1 to 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    myFile.close();
```

my question is: does the inner `for` is right? in `file.txt` all of my values are between -1 to 1 so i think it is good but i am not sure, do i go over the .wav file correctly and does the way i put it in the "file.txt" is good( does the "file.txt" contains the "y-axis" value of the function of the file, where the "x-axis" is the time)

Comment: There is a bug in your code as posted here - there's a variable `hi` that is not declared. Also, it would be helpful if you could say what error has come up that makes you think there's a problem with your program.

Comment: i wrote `hi` instead of `h`, i edit it in. and i dont get any errors, but because i took the `int h = (signed char)buff[i + 1];
                int c = (h << 8) | buff[i];
                double t = c / 32768.0;` from the internet, so i dont know if it is the right way to calculate `t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly right.  You're not checking the wav header to verify that the wave file actually contains 16 bit samples.

Your calculation of the 16 bit value is wrong, since `buff` is an array of `short int`.  The calculation you use would be correct if `buff` was a `char` array (but then you'd have to increment `i` by 2).

With the `short int` array, you can just say `int c = buff[i];` unless your system is a big-endian system.

The check for `abs(t) > 1` is unnecessary since -1.0 <= `c` < 1.0.

Comment: so to change `int h = (signed char)buff[i + 1];
                int c = (h << 8) | buff[i];` into `int c = buff[i];`?

Comment: @YuvalPaz Correct.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but i was told that the `for` need to be `for (...;...; i += wav->num_channels)` and not `for (...;...; i += 1)`, does it matters?

Comment: @YuvalPaz You're only processing 1 channel in your loop so incrementing `i` would allow you to get to all the samples.  If you only want the audio data from one channel, then incrementing by the number of channels would be appropriate.